# Recursion to create a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am having trouble comprehending recursion. I am trying to build a dictionary when a list of tuples containing (name, price), and I want to ensure the price is less than budget and create a dictionary where the name is the key and price is the value. I keep getting back an empty dictionary and I am not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def findstore(storelist, budget):
    store_dict = {}
    for key, value in storelist:
        if value in storelist < budget:
              value = findstore(value)
              store_dict[key] = value
    return store_dict

stores = [('Shaws', 2.50), ('PriceChopper', 3.99)]
budget = 2.99
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to use a python comprehension for this -

```py
stores = [('Shaws', 2.50), ('PriceChopper', 3.99), ('TheClipper', 1.99)]
budget = 2.99
dd = { s: p for (s, p) in stores if p <= budget }
print(dd)
```

```
{'Shaws': 2.5, 'TheClipper': 1.99}
```